# Turn ON Screen and Stop Screensaver from Service

Tags: android

I have a service which should wake up device and stop the screensaver when it receives intent. Any ideas how to accomplish that?

When in activity I would usually do something like this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

or

```
getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

The problem is I don't have `Window` in service.

Answer (score 0):

in your Receiver

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

    BroadcastReceiver screenOnOff = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        public static final String ScreenOff = "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF";
        public static final String ScreenOn = "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON";

        public void onReceive(Context contex, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ScreenOff))
            {
                Log.e("Log", "Screen Off"); 
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(ScreenOn))
            {
                Log.e("Log", "Screen On"); 
            }
        }
    };
```